# Designing a simple database from entity relationships

Tags: database, database-design, nosql

I have very little experience with database design and need to design one for a project I am building. It is fairly simple but once I draw out the ER diagram and apply the theory (according to my understanding), a complex design comes out and I don't think it is correct. [image: ER that I came up with]

The problem is as follows:
An MC is an entity set which has a unique ID but can exist in many "markets" like US, CA, DE etc., so id = 2 and market = US fully quantify an MC. An MC can be owned by zero or more LDAP groups and zero or more POSIX groups (but at least one one of those). e.g. id = 2 in market = US could be owned by LDAP 1, LDAP 2 and POSIX 3. But id =2 in market = CA could be owned by just POSIX 4. There is a many to many relationship between MCs and groups. Many LDAP/POSIX groups can own many MCs and vice-versa.

Based on the problem a. I do not know whether the ER diagram is correct b. If it is I don't know how to get relations from this diagram. I came up with MC(ID, name), LDAP(name), POSIX(name), LDAPMC(ID, market, name), POSIXMC(ID, market, name) but that seems way too complicated. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The diagram looks OK, but is missing cardinality information. You need to specify how many are at the each end of the relationship. From your description, I assume that it is:

MC - LDAP

- 1 MC can point to many, 1 or 0 LDAPs (0..* where * == many)
- 1 LDAP can point to many, 1 to 0 MCs (also 0..*).

MC to POSIX is the same. (other cardinalities are 1..* - may be many but must be 1; 0..1 - 0 or at most 1; and 1 - must be 1).

In this case you end up with Many-Many relationships: MC can have many LDAPs, LDAP can have many MCs. These are traditionally done via an 'association' table:

```
create table LDAPtoMC
(
    LDAPId, MCId -- these make up the PK, with an additional index on MCId
)
```

...where MCId is the PK of MC, LDAPId is the PK of LDAP.

If you had 1 MC must have 0 or 1 LDAP, LDAP may have 0 or many MC, you'd add LDAPId as a nullable field to MC and create a Foreign Key from that to the LDAP table. You wouldn't need anything on the LDAP table.

If the relationship was 1 MC must have 1 LDAP, 1 LDAP has 0..1 MC, then add an FK to MC as above but make it a non-nullable column. Add a nullable column to LDAP as an FK to MC.

And so on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should have formatted the question better to make it more readable but I did mention the cardinalities in the question. You are correct, MC to LDAP and MC to POSIX are both many-to-many. I also mentioned the  relations I came up with. One each for MC, LDAP and POSIX and then two 'association' tables LDAPMC AND POSIXMC. Are the individual tables for LDAP, POSIX and MC necessary or do I just need the association tables? Also, what do you  mean when you say 'an additional index on MCId'? I've heard this phrase floating around before but I am not sure what it means.